# Too many open processes when using multiprocessing. How close earlier processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, openstreetmap

I'm new to multiprocessing and need it for processing OpenStreet data. I use Python 3.5. I'm aware that there are some questions touching the topic. But I would prefer a solution with the Process class. Of course, other suggestions are welcome.

```
import overpy
api = overpy.Overpass()
result = api.query("""area[name="Aachen"]->.a;(rel(area.a)["building"];way(area.a)["building"];);(._;>;);out;""")

import multiprocessing as mp

def transfer(i,send_end):
    way = result.ways[i]

    bldg =  {'id':way.id,
             'nodeid':[way.nodes[h].id for h in range(len(way.nodes))],
             'coords':[(way.nodes[j].lat, way.nodes[j].lon) for j in range(len(way.nodes))],
            'tags':way.tags} 
    send_end.send(bldg)


if __name__=='__main__':
    jobs = []
    pipe_list = []
    for i in range(10000):
        recv_end, send_end = mp.Pipe(False)
        p = mp.Process(target=transfer,args=(i,send_end))
        jobs.append(p)
        pipe_list.append(recv_end)
        p.start()
   for proc in jobs:
       proc.join()

   result_list = [x.recv() for x in pipe_list]
```

The problem is that there are around 60.000 objects, and thus so many processes will be started. This overwhelms my system and triggers:

```
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

Has anybody an idea how to liberate resources before the end of the loop? I tried to use join() within the loop but then, I don't know why, it won't use all the cores.

Comment: How about not creating so many processes in the first place.  Have a pool of worker processes, maybe one per CPU (or more depending on I/O vs CPU time), and have each worker reading from an input Queue.  Put items to process onto the input Queue until no more items.  Then send None on the Queue to tell the workers to exit (exit their read-process loop).

Comment: I agree that Pool is more appropriated in this case. However, I'm just curious about a solution with Process to foster my understanding. I m sure it is possible but I miss something. Besides, a read few times that Pipe is more efficient than Queue.

Comment: You do not literally need to use `Pool` (although that would probably make sense).  The point is to use a limited number of processes over which the processing is spread out.  Also, you do not have to `Queue` specifically.  You can use any suitable IPC mechanism  (queue, pipe, socket, etc.).  The point is to have some way to provide input so that one of the worker processes can read it.